# Android setScroll position

Tags: android

I want to set scrollbar position becomes view visible.

I use

```
mView.setScrollY(150);
mView.setVisbility(View.VISIBLE);
```

But it's not worked. View stay visible but scroll position is 0.

Also i try to use a `post` :

```
mView.post(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mView.setScrollY(150);
        mView.setVisbility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

But now view was blinked( i see a start scrolly - 0 and after such ms(blink) scrollY becomes 150);

Any Ideas?

Comment: is mView a `ScrollView`?